# Update Text Field after font change (Win32)

Tags: c++, winapi

After I use setcontrolfont, the text of the text field does not update. The onnly way I fixed this is by removing then readding all text but this seems hackish. How can I do it properly? 
Thanks

*its a function I made:

```
void SetControlFont(HWND hand, int size, char* name)
{
    HGDIOBJ hfDefault;
    hfDefault = (HGDIOBJ)CreateFontA(size, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0,name);
    SendMessage(hand, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)hfDefault, MAKELPARAM(FALSE, 0));
}
```

Comment: I don't think `SetControlFont` is a Win32 function. Are you using a particular framework?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SendMessage(hand, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)hfDefault, MAKELPARAM(FALSE, 0))
```

The `MAKELPARAM(FALSE, 0)` is telling the window that it should not redraw itself.  Have you tried using `MAKELPARAM(TRUE, 0)` instead?

---

If you do not want to change the `SetControlFont` function, you could tell the text field to redraw itself after calling `SetControlFont` by calling `RedrawWindow`.